# Determining Object Type from JSON

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have an event that gives me a JSON string:

```
...
public delegate void DataReceivedHandler(string jsonString);
...
public event DataReceivedHandler OnDataReceived = null;
...
if(OnDataReceived != null)
{
    OnDataReceived(jsonString);
}
...
```

That JSON string could be one of 3 different complex objects: LogOnMessage, LogOffMessage, or DataRequest. Each message has a unique set of fields and properties.

**How can I determine which object type the JSON string resolves to?**

I know I can write a method that iterates through the JProperty.Name of the JObject and find a match by iterating through my collection of objects and their meta-data, but my gut tells me this is a common challenge to be solved so it must be built in to Newtonsoft JSON .NET somewhere that I simply am overlooking or not understanding. It's probably better and faster than my solution would be too...

Comment: There's no such thing as an "object type" nor any other kind of metadata in JSON.     Consider encapsulating the message inside some kind of envelope or other wrapper object.    Alternatively, send the data type / metadata as a separate parameter/structure

Comment: When doing this via our internal app we passed request header with type for de-serialization, if that is an option for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to detect object type by using JObjects and JsonSchemas.

Steps I Took:

1. Added a Schema property to my message objects that exposed a _schema field. The first time the property is called, it populates _schema with the return value of JsonSchemaGenerator.Generate(object o).
2. Convert the JSON string into a JObject via the JObject.Parse() static method.
3. There is an extension method in Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Extensions that can compare a JObject to a JsonSchema and determine if they match.

Please note: the methods above have been moved to a separate Newtonsoft.Schema library. So my recommendation is to utilize the latest and greatest library.

```
private Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchema _schema;  
public static Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchema Schema
{
    get
    {
        if (_schema == null)
        {
            Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaGenerator generator = new Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaGenerator();
            _schema = generator.Generate(typeof(DataResponse));
        }
        return _schema;
    }
}
...
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject message = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json); 
if(Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Extensions.IsValid(message, DataResponse.Schema))
{...}
else if (Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Extensions.IsValid(message, ServerStatus.Schema))
{...}
...
```